# VB equivalent of testing some return value

Tags: vb.net

In C I can do this:

```
if(e=my_func()){
...
}
```

There is some equivalent in VB?

Comment: That does work also in VB.NET if `e` is of the same type(or convertible to) the return value of `my_func`, what problem do you have?

Comment: Um... (e=my_func()) is an assignment. So, no, you can't do that in VB in an if statement.

Comment: @TimSchmelter in C, the example code results in an assignment to `e`, while in VB 6, it would not.  I haven't used VB.NET recently enough to remember, but I suppose it works like VB 6 in this regard.

Comment: @phoog: OP has not mentioned that he wants to assign something. The code works in the way that it allows to compare a variable with a return value of a method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter but the sample code is testing the return value *to see whether it implicitly converts to boolean "true"*, not to see whether it is equal to `e`.  The behavior of the sample code doesn't depend on the original value of e, because that value is overwritten by the assigment statement before the if-condition is evaluated.  In other words, the OP mentioned that he wanted to assign something by including the sample code.  Either he *does* want to assign something, or the sample code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the equivalent is this:

```
e = my_func()
If e Then
    '...
```

You also have to keep in mind that VB has different rules for implicitly converting values to the Boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function returning something. Let's say it is a boolean.

```
Function x() As Boolean
     Return True
End Function
```

Now you can check it like this:

```
  If x() = True Then
        'do something
  End If
```

or more simply:

```
   If x() Then
            'do something
   End If
```

Here is other possibilities, just to make it clear.

```
Function x() As Integer
     Return 5
End Function

If x() = 5 Then
    'do something
End If

If Not (x() = 5) Then
    'do something
End If

Dim y as Integer
y = x()

If y = 5 Then
    'do something
End If
```

Comment: OK, so more precisely, in C I can do'it in one piece, test for != false (meaning anything but 0 will be evaluated as true) and also assign return code to variable e, so I use that value inside if{} block. I guess VB wants strict boolean there.

Comment: @user1797147 “VB wants strict boolean there” – it does but that’s not relevant here. VB simply doesn’t allow an assignment inside an expression. Even with a boolean type this statement wouldn’t work. That is, `If b = SomeFunction() Then …` wouldn’t do what you want even if `b` were declared `As Boolean` and `SomeFunction` returned a `Boolean`.